# couchDB full package with all dependencies for windows

Tags: windows, couchdb, exe, couchbase

I want to install cocuhDB in my  window 7 and download couchDB from apache but it require install some dependencies first.
so in short i want any exe(package) that install couchDB in my system with dependencies just like XAMPP or WAMPP.
Is there any package available or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a 32-bit Windows executable available on the [CouchBase site](http://www.couchbase.com/downloads/couchbase-single-server/community).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [download page](http://www.couchbase.com/downloads) on the [CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com/) website, they have a few different packages available. When it was CouchOne (before becoming CouchBase) there was an exe installer, I'm not sure if the packages here are the same.

Comment: Ok now i would like to share what i got after follow Dominic Barnes instruction    

Download exe from:    
http://www.couchbase.com/downloads/moxi-server/community    
exe for windows     

After Installing this memcache It gives me option to create     
Data buckets     
Nodes     
etc...     

After setup full process     
now i have server where i am able to store and retrieve documents     

At end my couchDB server running and i am able to communicate with it.     

Thank you again Dominic Barnes.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a pure Apache CouchDB build at https://github.com/dch/couchdb/downloads